# World of Warriors - how to play?

Tags: world-of-warriors

I've been googling away, but I just can't find any resources that explain the rules of how to play World of Warriors (the Topps card game, not that app).

Does anyone know a resource? Or could anyone explain the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- WORLD OF WARRIORS is a game for 2 players. The aim of the game is to defeat your opponent’s team of warriors.
- Choose 12 warrior cards each and place them face down into 3 piles of 4 cards. Decide who will go first.
- Player 1 picks their first warrior to attack with. If player 1's warrior's attack is greater than player 2's warrior's health, they win and place their card in the *won* pile. The loser places their card in their *lost* pile.
- Players should also compare elements. If player 1’s element is stronger than player 2 they can add their elemental power boost to their attack score. If player 2’s element is stronger than player 1 they can add the elemental power boost to their health score.

  - **fire** is strong against earth, and weak against water. Air has no effect.
  - **earth** is strong against air, and weak against fire. Water has no effect.
  - **air** is strong against water, and weak against earth. Fire has no effect.
  - **￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼water** is strong against fire, and weak against air. Earth has no effect.
- If there is a draw, refer to the *Armour* score.
- You can use one talisman card per game. The talisman boost rating is added onto your warrior's attack or health score.
- Play continues, taking it in turns to attack the other warrior’s health.